# Why did the Rambam single out Ribui?

Tags: midrash, rambam, mitzvah

In [Sefer HaMitzvos, Shoresh 2](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaMitzvot%2C_Shorashim.2), the Rambam says that anything derived using Rabbi Yishmael's 13 principles of derivation, **or a Ribui** (extraneous wording which tells us to include new laws), does not get included in the 613 *mitzvos*.

I'm wondering why the Rambam singled out Ribui, considering there are many other principles of derivation besides ribui not included in the 13 of Rabbi Yishmael (see [Rabbi Eliezer's 32 middos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baraita_on_the_Thirty-two_Rules)). Different reasons given why Ribui is excluded from the 13, but why did the Rambam specify Ribui? Why not say "or any other principle of derivation"? For example, a hekesh is also not included in the 13 principles. Why didn't the Rambam say "the 13 principles, or a ribui, or a hekesh", or simply just mention hekesh? What's special about ribui?

He definitely doesn't mean that ribui isn't included, but hekesh is included, as evident from Mishneh Torah Hilchos Ishus 1:2 (see the Nosei Keilim there).

Is it perhaps that there are no *mitzvos* derived through hekesh, but there are through a ribui, and he has to argue that even so they are not in the 613? Does anyone talk about this?

Comment: Rambam says there (in [R. Qafih's tanslation](https://www.daat.ac.il/DAAT/mahshevt/hamitsvot/klal2-2.htm)): "גם זה כלל שכבר נשתבש בו זולתנו, ולפיכך מנה יראת חכמים בכלל מצוות עשה. ומה שהביאו לידי כך, כפי הנראה לי, דברי ר' עקיבא: 'את ה' אלקיך תירא' (דברים ו, יג) - לרבות תלמידי חכמים. וחשבו שכל מה שנלמד **בריבוי**, הוא מן הכלל הנזכר" (Ibn Tibbon, in Sefaria, brings "משלש עשרה מדות" instead of "בריבוי"). This is because _Halakhot Gedolot_ has "ליראה מן החכמים" as his _Mitzvat Aseh_ No. 155 (see starting [here](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20323&pgnum=141), at the end of the page).

Comment: @TamirEvan yes in every edition of Sefer HaMitzvos he attacks the Bahag's usage of ribui to learn that *mitzvah*, which would help explain why he mentions ribui, but my question is why not specify other *middos*. I guess it would help if I find a *mitzvah* counted by Bahag and his camp that is derived through a different *middah*...